# Double numbers output gets truncated

Tags: c++, double, output

I have a problem where I need to print some double value using basic C++ output system (such as iostream or sstream) and this value somehow gets truncated a lot. 
For example:

```
  double a = 283752.24234;
  std::cout << 283752.24234 << std::endl;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Both of the outputs will be 283752

Why is this happening and what can I do to get complete output of any double value?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker `flush()` actually might be wanted for this example. Don't confuse the OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I don't see it. It's routine output. `flush()` is pointless.

Comment: @PeteBecker Why shouldn't I use `std::endl` in cases like this?

Comment: @user4699276 - because it does things that you don't need. It's a bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening ...

That's because the [default precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is 6 and thus only the foremost 6 digits are rendered `283752`.

> ... and what can I do to get complete output of any double value?

1. First option is to use a bigger `precision` value using the [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) I/O manipulator:

   ```
   #include <iostream>  
   #include <iomanip>

   int main(){
       double a = 283752.24234;

       std::cout << std::setprecision(12) <<  283752.24234 << std::endl;
       std::cout << std::setprecision(12) <<  a << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c758e45f6f9b621e)
2. Second option is to use the [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) I/O manipulator to show the values after the decimal point:

   ```
   #include <iostream>  
   #include <iomanip>

   int main(){
       double a = 283752.24234;

       std::cout << std::fixed <<  283752.24234 << std::endl;
       std::cout << std::fixed <<  a << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b54e31ccdfdf1c32)

Output:

```
283752.242340
283752.242340
```